# Extract unique value from nested document in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

The database looks like the following:

```
"INC" : {
                "SIIB" : {
                    "Description" : "Interest Income, Bank",
                    "Value" : 66.06941
                },
                "STIE" : {
                    "Description" : "Total Interest Expense",
                    "Value" : 6.90925
                },
                "ENII" : {
                    "Description" : "Net Interest Income",
                    "Value" : 59.16016
```

[image]

How can I get all the distinct Description?

Comment: Please post sample document instead of screenshots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for something like this:

```
db.getCollection('pets').aggregate({
    $unwind: "$Annual" // flatten the "Annual" array into separate documents
}, {
    $project: { // transform "INC" subdocuments into key-value pair
        "inc": {
            $objectToArray: "$Annual.INC"
        }
    }
}, {
    $group: {  // get all distinct values across all documents
        "_id": null,
        "distinctValues": { $addToSet: "$inc.v.Description" }
    }
})
```

Comment: $objectToArray is what I am missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can just try to get only `distinct`/ `Unique` Description in array.

```
db.getCollection('Authors').distinct("Annual.INC.SIIB.Description")
```

> Tested in Mongo GUI.

Sample Doc :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b6a9bf571ace9eea8e64a04"),
    "name" : "userName",
    "avatar" : "avtarDetail",
    "Annual" : [ 
        {
            "INC" : {
                "SIIB" : {
                    "Description" : "Interest Income, Bank",
                    "Value" : 66.06941
                },
                "STIE" : {
                    "Description" : "Total Interest Expense",
                    "Value" : 6.90925
                },
                "STIEE" : {
                    "Description" : "Total Interest Expense",
                    "Value" : 6.90925
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

OutPut :

```
[
    "Interest Income, Bank"
]
```